# conditional expectation of non-negative variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation

In Angrist's book *Mostly Harmless Econometrics*, section 3.4.2, it says
$$ E[Y_i|D_i]=E[Y_i|Y_i>0,D_i]P[Y_i>0|D_i] $$, where $Y_i$ is a non-negative variable ($Y_i$ can be $0$) and $D_i$ is a dummy variable ($0$ and $1$).

I can somehow understand it intuitively, but I want a strict proof.

A discrete case is okay. Please avoid notations about measure theory since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Do you know the Law of Total Expectation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: I know the law of total expectation and iterated expectation basically. But I'm a little confused about the application of these laws on conditional expectation, especially the case that the condition contains the random variable too. Sorry for my silly question.

Comment: $E[Y_i|Y_i>0,D_i]=\frac{E[Y_iI_{(0,\infty)}(Y_i)|D_i]}{P[Y_i>0|D_i]}$, but in this case $Y_iI_{(0,\infty)}(Y_i)=Y_i$

Comment: At a high level, you can think of conditioning on a variable as simply inducing a new probability law. So you can do whatever you know of without conditioning, you can do with conditioning. For example, in the standard case, you know that the law of total expectation looks like $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X|A]\Pr(A) + \mathbb{E}[X|A^c] \Pr(A^c)$. Here $A$ is some event and $A^c$ is its complement and the expectation is with respect to the probability law under which the probability of $A$ is calculated.

Comment: Now if I condition on some event $B$, you can simply add the conditioning on all the terms implying that you are computing probabilities and expectations with this new law. So the law of total expectation will now read as $\mathbb{E}[X|B] = \mathbb{E}[X|A, B] \Pr(A|B) + \mathbb{E}[X|A^c, B] \Pr(A^c|B)$. You can extend this to random variables as well with the same idea. In your question, the event $A$ is $\{Y > 0\}$ and $A^c = \{Y \leq 0\} = \{Y = 0\}$, as $Y$ is a non-negative random variable and $B$ is equivalent to $D_i$.

Comment: Thus, $\mathbb{E}[Y_i|D_i] = \mathbb{E}[Y_i|Y_i > 0, D_i] \Pr(Y_i > 0|D_i) + \mathbb{E}[Y_i|Y_i = 0, D_i] \Pr(Y_i = 0|D_i)$. Now, conditioning on $Y_i = 0$, the expected value of $Y_i$ is $0$, so the second term vanishes giving the result. Note that all this explanation is intuitive like you wanted (so I have skipped some rigor). However, if you continue studying probability, I would suggest to eventually understand these ideas in measure theoretic terms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll go more in measure theory.